# In-place sorting of a row in an Eigen matrix

Tags: sorting, matrix, storage, eigen

I have written the following code to sort a specific line from en Eigen matrix:

```
Eigen::Matrix<int, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor> a(3, 3);

a << 3,2,1,
     12,5,6,
     7,8,42;

std::sort(a.row(1).data(), a.row(1).data() + a.row(1).size());
```

If I specify a row-major order, it works and carries out the correct in-place sorting. However, if the matrix is column-major, troubles arise, and the sorted matrix is:

```
3 12  1
2  5  6
7  8 42
```

I understand why this happen. I would like to know if there is a simple solution to sort in place a single line or column in Eigen regardless of the order. Since I sort the lines one by one on the whole matrix, the solution could sort the content of each individual line without having to manually loop on lines of the matrix.

Comment: I could copy a row, sort it, then copy it back into the matrix, but that seems sub-optimal to me.